# How do I prevent suggestions in the location bar in Firefox with history empty?

Tags: firefox, history

You know what I mean, when you type a letter in the internet browsers address bar it shows suggestions, like when you type <kbd>y</kbd> it suggests `youtube.com`. I believe this has to do with the history of visited web sites.

I want to delete one such site suggestion but it is not in the Firefox history.

How do I delete it in this case?

Comment: Maybe it is in your bookmarks?

Answer (score 3):

Even though the suggestion settings in Firefox 18 allow you to disable all, it won't do it!

[image]

Make sure the above setting in "Privacy" is set to "Nothing" (if you want to disable them).

Either way, **search suggestions** are still enabled. To disable this:

1. Go to `about:config` in the address bar
2. Click the "I'll be careful, I promise!" button.
3. In the search at the bottom of the "page", enter: `suggest`
4. You'll find this result: `browser.search.suggest.enabled`
5. *Double-click* this item to toggle its value to `false`.

Enjoy!

Below is a screenshot in case you find my steps described a bit hard to follow.

[image]

Comment: But OP seems to want to get rid of just one entry.

Comment: @vasa1 Yeah, I know. Without disabling search suggestions you won't get far as you don't have control over them at all.

Comment: If i do that, does it mean that there are no sugestions any more at all? Is there no way to just delete that one suggestion which doesnt appear in the history?

Comment: @ygoygo My answer's point is that these are *search suggestions*. You have no control over them, just like you can't delete entries from Google results yourself! All you can do is leave regular suggestions on, and disable the search suggestions.

Comment: @gertvdijk But google results aren't saved on my computer, the suggestion must be saved somewhere on my computer so I can delete only that one link so thatmore frequently used sites come up as search suggestions.

Comment: @ygoygo I re-read your comment three times, and I can't get what you're trying to say. You can't "save Google" - search suggestions are an interactive service, not a local database or something. Your local history and bookmarks *are* and you can control those.

Comment: @gertvdijk According to your last comment I should be able to delete one link of the suggestions which come up when I type a letter in the address bar without deleting my entire history or disabling the suggestion-function, because it is saved somewhere on my computer. But I could neither find it in Firefox -> History -> Show All History and neither in the bookmarks. And as you said it isn't a Google-search result because I dont get those when I type a letter in the adress-box.

Answer (score 2):

As you start typing, Firefox presents a drop-down menu of previously-visited websites.

Simply use your <kbd>down-arrow</kbd> to scroll to the one you want to delete, and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button. Done!

Comment: Wow, good suggestion, but doesn't work completely in my case at least. While the suggestion isn't showed as an option *below* the bar anymore, it is completed *within* the bar itself still... (using `y` from the OP's example) Still +1 for this simple (too obvious?) approach.

Comment: I did the same as Paddy Landau said and for me it worked, so it neither shows the suggestion nor completes within the bar itself. Thanks all who helped for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Tools → Clear Recent History ?
 Maybe some addresses "suggested" by firefox have been visited by you before the "range of clearing".

Comment: But shouldnt it appear when i type the site in search and click "this month", im sure i visited that site just recently.

Comment: I can suggest to remove "all" (in contrast to one/two hours) history but for "Browsing&Download history" only.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> and select "everything"

**update:** <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> opens history frame. then search for target site(s), right click and select "delete" or "forget about this site"

Comment: I only want to delete that one suggestion.